# Re-Initialize jquery anythingslider

Tags: jquery-plugins

Currently, my anythingslider has too many slides to fit in the wrapper without wrapping some elements below the others.  This should make sense to users of this plugin.  I'd like to show/hide some of the invisible elements as the back/forward buttons are clicked.  My problem so far is that the plugin is looking for elements that have been hidden after it's been initialized.

Is there a way to re-initialize the plugin so all slides are up-to-date on the fly?

I  *really* hope this makes some sense!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality was added in [AnythingSlider](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) version 1.5... there have been a few updates since ;)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `anythingSlider();` will re initialize the the slider. No need to specify the options. Just call `$("#element").anythingSlider();`